# Chef: How to require ruby/mysql API in ruby_block?

Tags: mysql, ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm new in ruby and chef. I built up a chef server and bootstrap a node successfully. I want to access Mysql on node through my cookbook without Mysql and database cookbook. I used ruby/mysql API. It worked well when was programmed in a single ruby file. The code is as follows.

```
require "rubygems"
require "mysql"

begin
    con = Mysql.new("localhost", "root", "123")
    res = con.query("create database abc")
rescue Mysql::Error => e
    puts e.errno
    puts e.error
ensure
    con.close if con
end
```

But when I added this code to a ruby_block in my cookbook and chef-client it, I got the error on node.

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[test1]'
================================================================================

LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- mysql

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/db_test/recipes/default.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/db_test/recipes/default.rb

 11: ruby_block "test1" do
 12:        block do
 13:                require "rubygems"
 14:                require "mysql"
 15:
 16:                begin
 17:                        con = Mysql.new("localhost", "root", "123")
 18:                        res = con.query("create database abc")
 19:                rescue Mysql::Error => e
 20:                        puts e.errno
 21:                        puts e.error
 22:                ensure
 23:                        con.close if con
 24:                end
 25:        end
 26: #      action :run

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/db_test/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'

ruby_block("test1") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  block_name "test1"
  declared_type :ruby_block
  cookbook_name "db_test"
  recipe_name "default"
  block #<Proc:0x000000051907a8@/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/db_test/recipes/default.rb:12>
end


Running handlers:
[2015-04-07T22:14:12-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-04-07T22:14:12-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-04-07T22:14:12-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 0.962999999 seconds
[2015-04-07T22:14:12-04:00] ERROR: ruby_block[test1] (db_test::default line 11) had an error: LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql
[2015-04-07T22:14:12-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I couldn't figure out when the problem is. Could anyone help this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef runs in its own ruby instance (assuming you've installed using omnibus). You'll need to install the mysql gem into the Chef ruby using a [chef_gem](https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html) resource. Then you should be able to load the mysql ruby

Answer (score 0):

Add `chef_gem "mysql2"` at the top of your block before the require statement.